# Public key doesn't exist or is not readable

Tags: key, root, xiaomi

I'm trying to root my xiaomi vacuum and I'm up to the point i create the firmware.I created the ssh keys required ,however,when I try to create the image I get the error Public key doesn't exist or is not readable.I would assume it has to do something with the file being a .pub format, since the public key does exist,it's just that the terminal can't read it.If i try to open it via files it automatically opens with libreoffice,so I would assume I need somehow to show it how to open the .pub file.
Any ideas?
Keep in mind I no nothing about ubuntu or linux in general.I had to learn how to set up a vm and navigate through linux in a day .I used a guide on github to get to this point.
https://github.com/dgiese/dustcloud/wiki/VacuumRobots-manual-update-root-Howto

Answer (score 0):

my problem was the following: Downloading dgiese/dustcloud will create several sub folders such as dustcloud/devices/xiaomi-vacuum...
There is another firmware builder which is in conflict with step no. 6 from dgiese/dustcloud wiki.
The command in step 6 must be shortend so, it refers to the correct firmware builder, the correct key etc.
In my case the command was --> "sudo ./dustcloud/imagebuilder.sh -f v11_003468.fullos.pkg -k id_ed25519.pub" ... depending which firmware and key you are using. Good luck, guys!